# How to change negative complex number for multiplication?

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $z_1=12\big($cos$\displaystyle \frac{3\pi}{8}+i $sin$\displaystyle\frac{3\pi}{8}\big)$ and $z_2=4\big($ cos$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{8}-i$ sin $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{8}\big)$, find $z_1z_2$.

So, the general formula is that

> if $z_1=r_1($ cos $\theta_1 +i$ sin $\theta_1)$ and $z_2=r_2($ cos $\theta_2+i $ sin $\theta_2)$,
>
> then $z_1z_2=r_1r_2[$ cos $(\theta_1+\theta_2) +i$ sin $(\theta_1+\theta_2)]$

So, I do realise that I have to change the negative sign in $z_2=4\big($ cos$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{8}-i$ sin $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{8}\big)$ before I can use the formula, but how to do so?

Comment: Note that the $\text{sin}(\cdot)$ function is an odd function, So take that minus inside.

Comment: @mrs Do you mean that the sin(-) function equals to a positive sin function?

Comment: I meant that $-\sin(\pi/8)=\sin(\pi/8)$. However, for the cosine function $-\cos(\pi/8)=\cos(-\pi/8)$. So, $z_2=\text{cis}(-\pi/8)$. See the @Matt's below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos -\frac\pi 8= \cos\frac\pi 8$$
$$\sin -\frac\pi 8=-\sin\frac\pi 8$$
So
$$4(\cos\frac\pi 8-i\sin\frac\pi 8)=4(\cos-\frac\pi 8+i\sin-\frac\pi 8)$$